# How to change color of NSString in drawAtPoint

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this chunk of code here that draws a block with a one-character string on it:

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake([blok getLocation].x * xunit, [blok getLocation].y * yunit, 40, 40), [blok getImage].CGImage);
[[blok getSymbol] drawAtPoint:CGPointMake([blok getLocation].x * xunit+15, [blok getLocation].y * yunit) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]];
```

It's working fine, but I've been doing some layout changes, and now I need it so that the string drawn will be white. Using the methods for setting the fill color and the stroke color haven't done anything. Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), textColor);
```

For example:

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake([blok getLocation].x * xunit, [blok getLocation].y * yunit, 40, 40), [blok getImage].CGImage);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), textColor);
[[blok getSymbol] drawAtPoint:CGPointMake([blok getLocation].x * xunit+15, [blok getLocation].y * yunit) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]];
```

Comment: Okay, that did it. Strange, could've sworn that's what I was doing...oh well, problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Set the foregroundcolor in the attributes and use the draw withAttributes functions

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                            @[font, [UIColor whiteColor]]
                            forKeys:
                            @[NSFontAttributeName, NSForegroundColorAttributeName]];
[string drawInRect:frame withAttributes:attributes];
```

Comment: Or `[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor] }];`

Comment: For me at least, setting the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` attribute worked correctly, while the solution in the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I use for drawing labels:

```
- (void)_drawLabel:(NSString *)label withFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width 
           atPoint:(CGPoint)point withAlignment:(UITextAlignment)alignment color:(UIColor *)color
{
    // obtain current context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // save context state first
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // obtain size of drawn label
    CGSize size = [label sizeWithFont:font 
                             forWidth:width 
                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];

    // determine correct rect for this label
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y - (size.height / 2),
                             width, size.height);

    // set text color in context
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

    // draw text
    [label drawInRect:rect
             withFont:font
        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip
            alignment:alignment];

    // restore context state
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: I already tried CGContextSetFillColorWithColor, along with CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor

Comment: @RaysonK what I'm suggesting is to use my alternative solution, as I think I had the same problems with drawAtPoint and that's why I ended up using that

Comment: Actually, that method call ended up working. Thanks for the suggestion, though