# Jerky scrolling of UICollectionView because of text labels

Tags: objective-c, performance, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have got a problem with jerky scrolling of UICollectionView. My cell consists of picture and a few text labels.

I have tried to check what is causing this and when I disabled setting text for labels everything is smooth, when I set text for more than two labels scrolling is jerky again...

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Here is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ResultCell";
    ResultCellView *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self.artworksSavedForLater containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.saveForLaterButton.selected = YES;
    } else cell.saveForLaterButton.selected = NO;
    Artwork *artwork = [self.dataHelper.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.title.text = artwork.title;


    cell.owner.text = artwork.owner;
    cell.fields.text = artwork.fields;
    cell.numberOfViews.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",artwork.views];
    cell.numberOfLikes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",artwork.likes];
    cell.numberOfComments.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",artwork.comments];
    cell.publishedDate.text = artwork.publishedDate;
    if ([artwork.hasThumbnail boolValue]) {
        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("imagecache", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
            UIImage *productImage = [UIImage imageWithData:artwork.thumbnail];
            CGSize imageSize = productImage.size;
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
            [productImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
            productImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                cell.thumbnailImage.image = productImage;
                cell.thumbnailImage.hidden = NO;
            });
        });


    }
    else {
        cell.thumbnailImage.hidden = YES;
        [self startOperationsForPhotoRecord:artwork atIndexPath:indexPath];

    }




    return cell;
```

Code for my cell:

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];



    self.title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"VerbRegular" size:14.0];

    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.19f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;



}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.thumbnailImage.image = nil;
}
```

Comment: are views and likes relationships in core data?

Comment: no - all data is stored as attributes of the same entity

Comment: run the app using instruments and see where the most time is being spent. are you doing any work in the setter methods on the cell? if you comment out the image processing does it improve?

Comment: No if I comment out the image processing it does not improve, it improves only when I comment out setting the text for labels... In instruments the most of time is being spent in this method  -[BGViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]and  -[ResultCellView prepareForReuse]. In my cell I'm only setting font, colours etc in -[didMoveToSuperView] and I am setting UIImage to nil in -[prepareForReuse]

Comment: i'm not sure then. setting text on a label shouldnt cause problems, unless you have a lot of them. maybe show your cell subclass code too?

Comment: I've read sometime ago that someone had a trouble with labels and instead of using them in an UICollectionView he drew the text... But I can't find this now...

Comment: I've had a few cells with many labels and havent seen any significant slow down. can you try removing the core data object, and setting the label text to @"test" or something like that?

Comment: Have you tried moving the lines where you set the font and background color to another method, like an init method?  That way it will only get called when the cell is created.

Comment: You might try switching to a built-in font.

Comment: I've tried to move this font and background settings to another method. I've tried using a built-in font. Neither of these results in better performance... But when I set text labels to @"test" as wattson12 suggested scrolling is smooth. I don't understand why image from the core data object isn't affecting the performance but text for a few labels is? Any suggestion how can I solve it? Should I cache text from the core data somewhere before updating my UICollectionView?

Comment: So it seems that not core data causing this performance issue. I've copied all text from core data to NSMutableArray with NSDictionaries and I'm using     cell.title.text = self.textCache[indexPath.item][@"title"]; to set labels text. The scrolling is again jerky and I have run out of ideas what's wrong.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a sample project and post it?

Comment: I've changed the data source for my UICollectionView to test it. I'm not using CoreData - it is an NSArray. My cell has got 7 labels. It seems that if you have got more than 3 labels which text is set dynamically scrolling can not be smooth... With seven labels it is really jerky. I think the only solution for me is to try to redesign UI to have less labels in a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to jerky scrolling for UICollectionView with many labels dynamically set.

Instead of using labels I draw all NSStrings using drawLabel method described by Miroslav Hudak in this post:

[How to change color of NSString in drawAtPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750137/how-to-change-color-of-nsstring-in-drawatpoint)

Now my UICollectionView is scrolling smoothly :)