# Changing UIFont color while writing in PDF using iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working with PDF . I am creating PDF programatically. I can write bold and italic format but unable to change the colour of the font if there is any suggestion? Thanks in advance 
my code is given below

```
 NSString *textToDraw3 = @"Installation Address Details:";

font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];

stringSize = [textToDraw3 sizeWithFont:font
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) 
                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 230.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

[textToDraw3 drawInRect:renderingRect 
               withFont:font
          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
              alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. You should be able to use the fillcolor to change the font color while drawing.

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11750163/904355)